# Calling asp.net webmethod from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have tried to call default.aspx/GetCompanyNames method from jquery. However, it could not hit the break point so data returns empty. When I checked response message which says Authentication failed. Then I search for, and found:
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent; to Off or should be commented. I tried both of the way but I am getting "500"

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#<%=txtCompanyName.ClientID%>').autocomplete
           ({
               source:
                   function (request, response) {
                       $.ajax
                       ({
                           url: '<%=ResolveUrl("Default.aspx/GetNames") %>',

                           data: "{ 'name': '" + JSON.stringify(request.term) + "' }",   // term is the property that contains the entered text
                           dataType: "json",
                           type: "POST",
                           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                           success: function (data) {
                               response(data["d"]);  // property d contains list of names sent from service
                           },
                           error: function (xhr, callStatus, errorThrown) {
                               alert(callStatus);
                           }
                       });
                   },
               minLength: 1
           });
    });
</script>

   <h3>Auto Complete Textbox without using Web Service</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Type Company Name: </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="ui-widget" style="text-align:left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" Width="350px" 
                                CssClass="textboxAuto"  Font-Size="12px" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>        
        </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> GetNames(string name)
{
    // for simplicity list is hard-coded
    List<string> l = new List<string> { "Java", "Ruby", "C#", "C++", "C", 
        "JavaScript", "VB", "Python", "Cobol" };
    return l.Where(s => s.ToLower().StartsWith(name.ToLower())).ToList();

}
```

Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this issue? Thanks for yout help.

Comment: ScriptManager included Site.Manager. Actually I am new for webforms and jquery

Comment: Sry, just deleted my comment. Do you mean it's on the master page? In the Toolbox/Ajax Extensions, you can find ScriptManager.

Comment: Yes, it is included on master page

Comment: I think you can just say `url: "Default.aspx/GetNames",`.

Comment: Oh, you get `Authentication failed` error, which could be something else. Do you just need to log in?

Comment: @wazz I tried   url: "Default.aspx/GetNames", I dont need to log in

Comment: For AutoRedirectMode, did you try changing Permanent to Off? Those "friendly urls" can be a real pain. Nevermind, you tried both.

Comment: I tried it, but ı am getting 500

Comment: One last attempt - try `Default/GetNames`. Friendly urls might prefer without .aspx. ?? Otherwise, sounds like an auth/login issue.